# Return Matching Column using Google Scrips and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, lookup

I've been working on a script for my google sheet that takes a full string from a cell and compared them against a list of keywords on a second sheet, this should return the column number. There is more to go, but i'm having some trouble.

I have tried a few methods, and now I'm trying regex. I think I'm using it correctly. My logic is if the regex expression of the keywords matches any full word of the original query then return true and the column number.

I have got the cells in the "Tag's" sheet offset,. but its checking the right ranges.

```
function returnTag(narration){
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tagsheet = main.getSheetByName('Tags');
  var numRows = tagsheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = tagsheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = tagsheet.getRange(6, 2, numRows-5, numCols-1);
  var row;
  var col;

  for (var col = 1; col <= numCols-1; col++) {
    for (var row = 1; row <= numRows-5; row++) {
      var currentValue = range.getCell(row,col).getValue();
      var regExp = new RegExp("\b"+narration+"\b","gi");
      if(regExp.test(currentValue)) {
       return(col);
      }
      else{ }

    }          
  }   
}
```

I expect that if i type "There are plenty of fish in the sea" in A2 of the first sheet, it will return 2 as the column reference it was found in A1 of the first sheet.

I have shared a editable copy of the sheet below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FDT6ximWg4AcGzDTuqC4AYIW4MgXFwlUH0wYfGQi8s/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

- The `new RegExp()` ought to contain the **currentValue** and test the "narration" (your original code is doing the reverse)
- You don't need the word boundary `\b` within the `new RegExp()` function

Try this -

```
function returnTag(narration){
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tagsheet = main.getSheetByName('Tags');
  var numRows = tagsheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = tagsheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = tagsheet.getRange(6, 2, numRows-5, numCols-1);
  var row;
  var col;
  for (var col = 1; col <= numCols-1; col++) {
    for (var row = 1; row <= numRows-5; row++) {
      var currentValue = range.getCell(row,col).getValue();
      var regExp = new RegExp(currentValue,"gi");
      if(regExp.test(narration)) {
       return(col);
      }
      else{ }
    }          
  }   
}
```

I've updated the same in the sheet that has been shared too & it works now :)

Comment: Thank you! I thoguht it might have been something stupid like that :)

Just wondering, why is the word boundary not needed? I thought it would mean it would pull partial matches  / words.

Thanks :)